# Given $\tan A + \tan B = 3x$ and $\tan A \tan B = 2x^2$, find $\tan A - \tan B$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Given $$\tan A + \tan B = 3x$$ and $$\tan A \tan B = 2x^{2},$$ how can one find $\tan A - \tan B$? I have tried substitution, but failed to find the answer.

**Edit:** Can this problem be solved using the formulas for sums and differences of tangents?

Comment: Please show the substitution steps that you tried.

Answer (score 2):

We know that $$(a-b)^2=a^2+b^2-2ab=(a+b)^2-4ab$$ $$\implies a-b=\pm \sqrt{(a+b)^2-4ab}$$ Now, we have 
$$\tan A-\tan B=\sqrt{(\tan A+\tan B)^2-4\tan A\tan B}$$ $$=\sqrt{(3x)^2-4(2x^2)}$$ $$=\sqrt{x^2}$$$$=\pm x=|x|$$

Comment: $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$. To avoid sign issues, I'd explicitly assume that $\tan A\ge\tan B$ from the beginning, or I'd write $|\tan A-\tan B|$.

Comment: Yes, you are right

Comment: Why should $\tan A-\tan B$ be nonnegative?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

$$\sqrt{(\tan A+\tan B)^2-4\tan A\tan B}$$

Comment: ...And then take care of the sign issues.

Answer (score 0):

$tanA+tanB=3x$

Squaring both sides,we get

$tan^2A+tan^2B+2tanA tanB=9x^2$

Subtract $4tanA tanB$ from both sides,

$tan^2A+tan^2B-2tanA tanB=9x^2-4tanA tanB$

$(tan A-tan B)^2=9x^2-4tanA tanB$

Put $tanA tanB$ in above equation,

$(tan A-tan B)^2=9x^2-8x^2=x^2$

$tan A-tan B=\pm x$